# Re-create fragment properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to re-create Fragment. After I did something like

```
fragmentTransaction.detach(someFragment);
fragmentTransaction.attach(someFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

`onAttach` is not being called but only `onCreateView`, which means that fragment was not-really re-attached.

Please advise how to make full detach/attach cycle. Thank you!

Comment: This code is used to force `onCreateView`. `onAttach` and `onDetach` are called when the activity changes, so keep unrelated code out of these methods. `onCreate` is called only when the fragment is created so keep unrelated code out. If you need to do everything brand new you might as well instantiate a new fragment.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Yes, it makes sense, thanks! This is definitely an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code is used to force `onCreateView` (which may be useful at times).

`onAttach` and `onDetach` are called when the activity changes, so keep unrelated code out of these methods.

`onCreate` is called only when the fragment is created (which is once for retained fragment, otherwise once for each configuration change) so keep unrelated code out.

If you need to do everything brand new you might as well instantiate a new fragment and replace the original one.